# A solution for $x^x=2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I just stumbled upon this question and just can't figure out a way to prove it.

> Show that the equation $x^x=2$ has a solution in $\mathbb{R}^+$.

I'm just curious... can someone show me, how to prove this?

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)=x^x-2$ and examine the first derivative.

Comment: @mrtaurho, you don't even need a derivative.

Comment: Hint: use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @Mark Oh, yes you are right. However, I guess the crucial point is to work with the function $f(x)=x^x-2$.

Comment: Oh, of course! Thank you @abc...!

Comment: @mrtaurho You can apply the theorem to $x^x$ itself too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**: $f(x)=x^x-2$ is a continuous function in $(0,\infty)$. Can you prove it must be equal to zero at some point?

Comment: You mean by figuring out it's derivative?

Comment: No, you don't even need derivatives here. Do you know the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: Yes... @abc... just gave me that hint in the comments above. Now it's all clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Observe that the function takes value $1<2$ for $x=1$ and takes value $4>2$ for $x=2$.

Further the function is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ so you are allowed to use the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

Comment: You are absolutely right. @abc... already mentioned this, but nevertheless thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently to what drhab said, with $f(x)= x^x- 2$, $f(1)= 1^1- 2= 1- 2= -1$.  And $f(2)= 2^2- 2= 4- 2= 2$.  Since f(1)< 0 and f(2)> 0, **and** f is continuous, there exist x, between 1 and 2, such that $f(x)= x^x- 2= 0$ and so $x^x= 2$.